Augmenting LiDAR/DSM data from 3D models
For a viewshed analysis in QGIS 3.34, the I have LiDAR/DSM geotif files available. I want to modify/augment the DMS layer by adding the height information from 3d models of specific buildings. This has applications for simulating both cumulative (future effects) or updating older DSM with buildings that have been completed since the date of the data capture, creating a virtual current baseline DSM layer.
I have attempted to render orthographic Z-depth passes of those models, but couldn't find a way of transforming them into "LiDAR" tifs, and I'm not sure if that is at all possible via Gdal libraries.
Could you point me to way of accomplishing this though renders/Gdal route and patching the DSM?
